# undefined method `firstname' for nil:NilClass Rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Can somebody help me with this error? I add profile controller by console without model. Database it's working fine. I am sure that i have lastname and firstname in seed.rb and i just did db:setup/migration.

Here's the show.html

```
.page-header
  .h1
    =link_to @user.firstname + " " + @user.lastname, edit_user_registration_path
```

Database:

```
 create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "",    null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "",    null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,     null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "firstname"
    t.string   "lastname"
    t.string   "username"
    t.boolean  "admin",                  default: false
```

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_many :reviews
  has_many :products

  validates_presence_of :firstname, :lastname
end
```

Profile controler:

```
class ProfileController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @user = User.find_by_username(params[:id])
    if @user
      @reviews=@user.reviews.order(:created_at).reverse_order.limit(5)
      render action: :show
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Is `params[:id]` the id or the username? If its the id, you should use `#find` instead of `#find_by_username`

Comment: Your if statement doesn't do what you think it does. Rails will call `render :show` anyway, as that is the default action. So even if the user wasn't found, you are still rendering the page. you need to use `redirect_to`.

Comment: @Myst `redirect_to` show while being in show action?

Comment: @AndreyDeineko you will want to redirect to `index` or a different page. Otherwise you will end up in a redirect loop. But, if you don't redirect somewhere, the application will attempt to render `show` while `@user` is `nil`.

Comment: Remember to vote up answers that helped you. I voted up  @AndreyDeineko's answer, I feel it's a good one. Why don't you  so as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part

```
@user = User.find_by_username(params[:id])
```

returns `nil`, because you pass `id` from params as a `username` to `find_by_username` finder. In can't find the `username` (string) which is `id` (integer).

It should be

```
@user = User.find(params[:id])
```

[Take a look at docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html) on how finders work

Comment: It help with undefined method but i get another error: ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in ProfileController#show
Couldn't find User without an ID

Answer (score 0):

If you are using find_by_username then you should pass params[:username] instead of params[:id] .

Answer (score 0):

Also this part:

```
if @user
  @reviews=@user.reviews.order(:created_at).reverse_order.limit(5)
  render action: :show
end
```

even if the if statement is `false`, `render action: :show` will still be called - it's the default.

if you defined a method that said nothing:

```
def test
end
```

rails would call: `render action: :name_of_method`

You need to use a redirect and `unless`:

```
redirect_to users_url, notice: 'user not found' unless @user
```

Good luck!